# X230 fingerprint reader not visible

Tags: lenovo-laptop, fingerprint

My Lenovo X230 (2320-2LG) has fingerprint reader on it, but it's not visible in Windows (Windows 8 x64, clean install). I installed the ThinkVantage Fingerprint software (patch included), no luck. I was trying to find something in BIOS to enable but everything looks fine. Something is however strange. If I go in BIOS into Security > Fingeprint and try to erase all data, it tells me no fingerprint is attached.

Any idea what can be (I did) wrong?

Comment: Sounds like bad hardware (or disconnected) if it's not showing up anywhere.

Comment: Could be. Not sure how to check, for sure, whether it's somewhere somewhat disabled or it's simply broken.

Comment: If it's under warranty, just call Lenovo and let them dink with it. If there's no warranty and you're endeverous, pop open the case and poke around. If that doesn't fix it, the reader is likely toast (possibly from ESD) and you'd have to replace it. If something "sees" the reader and it's not working, that's probably a software issue (usually drivers, especially since most manufactures don't play nice with the WBF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the finger print reader was broken indeed (the laptop was 3 days old, bad luck). I had it replaced and now it works OK.